How could I setup a single ws endpoint for multiple browsers in playwright?
Essentially, I'd like to run my playwright browsers in a container for a cloud application. The test options do offer the setting to setup a remote wsEndpoint but this is for each browser. Is it possible to create a single endpoint for multiple browsers?

The only way, that I'm aware of, to have multiple browsers for automation behind a single URL would be to use a load balancer or similar service.
If you introduced a load balancer, you could have a single URL for the load balancer that would then route requests to browsers via browser unique URL's.
One thing to note is load balancers can be software or hardware. For instance, I think browserless.io uses a software-based load balancer to disribute requests across multiple browsers.
